# Proving a linear function is bounded using the Baire category theorem (or its consequences)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, baire-category

This is a problem from [Folland](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471317160).

- Let $\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{Y}$ be Banach spaces. If $T : \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$ is linear and $f \circ T \in \mathcal{X}^*$ for all $f \in \mathcal{Y}^*,$ then $T$ is bounded.

I am not sure how to go about proving it. It seems that I have to use the Baire category theorem in the form of the closed graph theorem; that is, it is sufficient to prove that $\Gamma(T) = \{(x, y) : x \in \mathcal{X}, y = Tx\}$ is closed in $\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}.$ But I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Note that $f\circ T=T^* f$. Use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle for $F=\{ T^* \}$...

Comment: I see the solution! Is it proper StackExchange etiquette to answer your own question?

Comment: I think that it would be fine if you write the solution here as an answer. This would help the other with the same problem.